# Web scraping Loop python issue

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am a python newbie, and wondering if someone would be able to highlight where about I am going wrong with the following webscraping script.

I am trying to recursively loop through the list of matches, to pull a cumulative  value (metric) for each match.

My problem is, it is returning the exact same value each time.

I've tried to add notes to explain each of my points, any help appreciated.

```
#use Selenium & Beautiful Soup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

#define URL/driver
my_url = "https://www.bet365.com/#/IP/"

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get(my_url)

#allow a sleep of 10 seconds
time.sleep(10)

#parse the page
pSource= driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pSource, "html.parser")


#containers tag - per match
containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ipn-TeamStack "})
for container in containers:
     #Total Match Shots
     cumul_match_shots = 0    
     match = container.find_all('div')
     for data in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'ml1-SoccerStatsBar '}):  
         for result in data.find_all('span'):
             a = result.text
             if len(a) > 0:
                 cumul_match_shots += int(a)
    #print out values
     print(match)
     print(cumul_match_shots)
#close the webpage
driver.close()           `
```

Comment: Why is your code not working for me? Is ipn.TeamStack even a class?

Comment: [<div class="ipn-TeamStack_Team">Southampton</div>, <div class="ipn-TeamStack_Team">Brighton</div>]
1
[<div class="ipn-TeamStack_Team">Girona</div>, <div class="ipn-TeamStack_Team">Celta Vigo</div>]
1

Comment: yes, class is there as above - I am getting the team container to loop but the value (1 on this example), is always the same for every result (not quite correct). I have tried the print in different places but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to change the indentation (and move it a little bit higher) of the print(cumul_match_shots), as in the current state - it will give (print) you always the value from the last for loop.

And I am not sure if you are have a right place to reset the value to 0 again. Currently it looks like it will be a cumulative value of score in ALL matches.

As for match - it should be ok, as you do not modify it in the for loops.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have tried in a few different places now but no luck